# PostgreSQL 10.1 incorrect division output

Tags: sql, postgresql, integer-division

Postgres is giving the wrong result for division when the denominator is greater than the numerator.

`select 2/4` gives 0, `select 4/2` works correct.

But `select 2/4` should actually return 0.5
but it is returning 0 as integer

Comment: That’s because it’s an integer division. PostgreSQL is working correctly. If you want a float division then cast to float first

Comment: And, please only tag it with the versions that you are using, rather than scattering random tags and versions on your quesiton.

Comment: Did you think that Postgres, one of the biggest DB systems in the world, had a bug where simple division didn't work correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Postgres does integer division on integers.  Ironically, it does not do integer averages on `avg()`, but that is a different matter.

One solution is simply converting one of the value to `numeric`:

```
select  2/4, 2::numeric/4
```

Postgres will add decimal places for numerics.

Answer (score 0):

Try a floating point division, as in:

```
select 2.0 / 4 -- shows 0.5
```

Or:

```
select 1.0 * 2 / 4 -- shows 0.5
```